# How to deploy contract into local running node using solidity browser?

Tags: contract-deployment, remix

I am running a local ethereum node and I did unlock an account.
Now I want to use the solidity browser to deploy that contract, but when I switch to the web3 provider deploy option and I press the Create button at the address 'http://localhost:8000' all I see is an error that says 'Error: account is locked'. I don't know why and how is this working?

Also what is the easiest way to deploy an smart contract into a local running node?

Answer (score 3):

I see you are changing the `Web3 Provider Endpoint` in Solidity Browser, and make sure to [unlock account](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#listing-accounts-and-checking-balances).

An alternative way is to just leave the default: `Javascript VM`, then:

1. Click `Create` and copy the values in `Web3 deploy`.
2. Open a Geth console with account 0 unlocked.
3. Paste the `Web3 deploy` values into the Geth console, and wait for your transaction to be mined.

Here's the `Web3 deploy` values for the simplest `contract Test {}` and you can see that `web3.eth.accounts[0]` needs to be unlocked (or change it to your unlocked account).

```
var testContract = web3.eth.contract([]);
var test = testContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '6060604052600a8060106000396000f360606040526008565b00', 
     gas: 3000000
   }, function(e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address != 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```