# Is it possible to link contracts to existing libraries from within geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I've been making and deploying contracts and libraries, deploying libraries first and then using the binary output from e.g.

```
$ solc --bin-runtime test.sol --libraries TestLib:0xb78f86ea662866b3131f79a886c17884e793f5c4
```

and copying the contract output and sending in a geth transaction as data.

Is there a way to link contracts to existing/previously deployed libraries and deploy from within the geth console, so that I don't have to independently define the ABI and keep switching between tabs?
If not, why not? And how do I use the ABI in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

All linking does is stick the library's address into another contract's bytecode. When you *don't* tell solc to link, it will put something like `__SomeLib________` (with a lot more underlines) where every reference to the library is. All you need to do is replace that placeholder with the address of your deployed contract.

See my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6951/1151) for one way to do it.

Comment: Ah thanks, cool work around! I was just wondering if there was anything more like --libraries but I guess if it works, it works