# How to link libraries in browser-solidity?

Tags: remix, library

How to link library in browser-solidity? While creating a contract using library, solidity compiler requires to link the contract with the library. But there is no options in the browser to provide it. Contract is not created as it has lib's placeholders in bytecode similar to  _______LibName_________

[image]

Comment: Related, for general info: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/what-are-the-steps-to-compile-and-deploy-a-library-in-solidity

Answer (score 10):

Browser-solidity is able to import library code from GitHub (importing from Swarm is [on the way](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/issues/357)).
E.g. you can write:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/library/stringUtils.sol";

contract test {
    function foo() returns (bool){
        string memory a = "hello";
        string memory b = "world";
        return StringUtils.equal(a, b);
    }
}
```

When you press `Create` button, two contracts will be created on the blockchain: one for the library code and another one for the contract. Library address will be linked into the `test` contract automatically.

---

Please note, that you need to drop `blob/<branch name>` from URL.

Original URL:
`https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/stringUtils.sol`

URL to import (without `https://` and `blob/master/`):
`github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/library/stringUtils.sol`