# How to call a library contract

Tags: solidity, library

`library ECVerify` is deployed on [0x3bbb367afe5075e0461f535d6ed2a640822edb1c](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x3bbb367afe5075e0461f535d6ed2a640822edb1c#code) on the Ropsten test net.

How do I call `function ecverify(bytes32 hash, bytes sig, address signer) returns (bool) {}` in that library contract from a `contract foo`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A library is similar to a contract and you can use an abstract contract to declare its interface and then invoke (like [Calling function from deployed contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/calling-function-from-deployed-contract)).

```
contract ECVerify {
    function ecverify(bytes32 hash, bytes sig, address signer) returns (bool);
}

contract Foo {
    ECVerify ecv = ECVerify(0x3bbb367afe5075e0461f535d6ed2a640822edb1c);

    function callEcv(bytes32 hash, bytes sig, address signer) {
        bool b = ecv.ecverify(hash, sig, signer);
        // handle b
    }
}
```

The main feature of a **library** is that its **code is executed in the context of the calling contract.**  [`library ECVerify`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x3bbb367afe5075e0461f535d6ed2a640822edb1c#code) does not access storage so the simple code above works, but it treats and executes just like any non-library contract.

The other case is a library that accesses storage, then your `Foo` contract should have the storage defined correctly: the library will be writing to *your* contract's storage.

[Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries) have an example of a `library Set`, which needs a `mapping(uint => bool)`.  This means that your contract should have this mapping.  Whenever the library writes to the mapping, it writes to the mapping in *your* contract.

Here's:

```
library Set {
  // We define a new struct datatype that will be used to
  // hold its data in the calling contract.


  struct Data { mapping(uint => bool) flags; }
  ...
```

and an example of defining the mapping in Foo:

```
contract Foo {
    Set.Data knownValues;
```

Another example of linking and calling a library is given in [What are the steps to compile and deploy a library in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/what-are-the-steps-to-compile-and-deploy-a-library-in-solidity)

Comment: From your example above: how does the compiler know that ``ecv.ecverify(hash, sig, signer)`` is a library call and has to be executed as delegatecall?

Comment: @ivicaa You're right delegatecall isn't used for ECVerify: delegatecall is not needed because ECVerify doesn't access storage.  (As mentioned in this answer, the last link and the Set example, provide more details on how to link and call a library that accesses storage.)