# Library calls fail depending on compiler version?

Tags: solidity, remix, library, compiler

I'm trying to deploy my library and call it afterwards with the specific address.
While testing this I encountered that the behavior changed over the course of compilers.

I tried to follow [How to call a library contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11743/how-to-call-a-library-contract) but the following inconsistency happened:

**Library 1**

```
pragma solidity 0.7.0;

library Seven {
    function seven() public returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Library 2**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.6;

library Foursix {
    function foursix() public returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Main Contract**

```
pragma solidity 0.7.0;
abstract contract Foursix {
    function foursix() virtual public returns (bool);
}

abstract contract Seven {
    function seven() virtual public returns (bool);
}

contract Foo {
    function callfoursix(address a) public {
        Foursix fs = Foursix(a);
        bool b = fs.foursix();
    }
    function callseven(address a) public {
        Seven s = Seven(a);
        bool b = s.seven();
    }
}
```

notice how Library 1 and 2 are identical besides the used compiler.
When testing in remix Library 1 gets the error:

*transact to Foo.callseven errored: VM error: revert.*

while the call to Library 2 succeeds.

Why is this the case and how do I call the Library 1 contract?
It does seem that ABI encoding has something to do with it as the newer version is seemingly not found but for the moment I'm clueless.

Comment: if you look in the linked thread, it's exactly how a library should be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out functions have to be declared as "view or pure" when called from outside after solidity version 0.5.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#call-protection-for-libraries

Comment: You wouldn't have to declare it `view` or `pure`, if you `FourSix` and `Seven` were libraries instead of an `abstract` contract. The problem here is that the compiler generates `call` instead of `delegatecall` to the address (because it doesn't know that it's calling a library.) And because of call protection, the call will revert. I would say that this is an incorrect usage of libraries.