# Contract creation gas cost depends on code in library function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, gas

I have a contract fooContract which is using a fooLib library, calling fooLib.foo(LibStruct storage param)

The transaction cost to **create** fooContract seems to depend on the code in the fooLib.foo() function despite the params are unchanged.

Ie. using solidity browser fooContract create costs 3,185,059. if I comment out the code in fooLib.foo(), the fooContract create cost goes down to 2,816,000 .

As far as I understood libs are a way to move out functionality for contracts too large for block gas limit.

Am I missing a point here?

Comment: This link could help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2760/6237

Comment: Thanks for that, it's indeed useful.
Although I'm not talking about the cost of the transaction to call fooLib.foo() but about the contract creation cost of fooContract.

Comment: Gas cost at creation depends on what happens in the constructor and the size of the compiled code, so what you describe seems normal.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect not using a library the way it's intended to achieve gas costs in your contract. I  assume what you're doing is something like:

```
library fooLib {
    // foo code
}

contract fooContract is fooLib {
    // foo code
}
```

In which case when you create `fooContract` you have to pay the compilation costs for `fooLib`. What you want to do is deploy fooLib on it's own, specify how to interact with the library via an `interface`, and specify the library address to link to with the solc compiler during compilation of `fooContract`. By doing this you would avoid having to pay the compilation cost of `fooLib` when deploying `fooContract` and instead just pay the transaction fees when utilizing the library.

The following stackexchange post has a solid detailed description of this process:

- [What are the steps to compile and deploy a library in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/what-are-the-steps-to-compile-and-deploy-a-library-in-solidity)

A very good aragon article on this:

- https://blog.aragon.one/library-driven-development-in-solidity-2bebcaf88736

Comment: second link in your answer is no longer active. 404 error

Answer (score 0):

The **internal** functions in libraries are pulled into the calling contract at compile time and a regular `JUMP` call is used instead of a `DELEGATECALL`. From Solidity docs: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#libraries

Comment: which is more expensive, jump or delegate call? will they both scale linearly? for example if I have 5 jumps the delegate call cost = 5 * delegate_call_jump_cost?