# Error: User contains unresolved libraries. You must deploy and link the following libraries before you can deploy a new version of User:

Tags: solidity, truffle, mapping

I followed to use [IterableMapping](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/iterable_mapping.sol) and when I compiled to `file.json` in property `unlinked_binary` I have this problem:

```
"0x6060604052341561000f5760008073__IterableMapping_______________________637e5236456000858560006040516020015260405160e060020a63ffffffff861602815260048101939093526024830191909152604482015260640160206040518083038186803b15156100e957600080fd5b6102c65a03f415156100fa57600080fd5b5050506040518051505060025490505b92915050565b60008060008073__IterableMapping_______________________63a21ab7166000806040516020015260405160e060020a63ffffffff8416028152600481019190915260240160206040518083038186803b151561016e57600080fd5b6102c65a03f4151561017f57600080fd5b50505060405180519350505b73__IterableMapping_______________________63c8fccc6960008560006040516020015260405160e060020a63ffffffff85160281526004810192909252602482015260440160206040518083038186803b15156101ea57600080fd5b6102c65a03f415156101fb57600080fd5b50505060405180519050156103145773__IterableMapping_______________________6375a3e8e860008560006040516040015260405160e060020a63ffffffff851602815260048101929092526024820152604401604080518083038186803b151561026857600080fd5b6102c65a03f4151561027957600080fd5b505050604051805190602001805190509150915080840193505b73__IterableMapping_______________________6388d0443760008560006040516020015260405160e060020a63ffffffff85160281526004810192909252602482015260440160206040518083038186803b15156102f257600080fd5b6102c65a03f4151561030357600080fd5b50505060405180519050925061018b565b5b505050905600a165627a7a7230582007e859ad90557930a0b17bf217193ef40e157f6492404defbb3b33f19b99edbe0029",
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by commenting lib file require statement in the migration file:

```
var User = artifacts.require("./User.sol");
//var itMapsLib = artifacts.require("./itMapsLib.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(User);
  //deployer.deploy(itMapsLib);

};
```

When execute command `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate` should include only contract file for deploy, not library or patterns from which they are inherited.

Comment: What about when executing command `truffle test`?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17558/what-does-deploy-link-exactly-do-in-truffle