# what does link mean in truffle?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-design, contract-deployment

I saw the following : [what does `deploy.link` exactly do in `truffle`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17558/what-does-deploy-link-exactly-do-in-truffle)

I have safe.sol

```
library safe {
   
    function safeMultiply(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            uint256 c = a * b;
            assert(c / a == b);
            return c;
        }
    }


}
```

In my contract, I have this:

```
import "../libraries/safe.sol";


contract TokenSale {

  function test() public view returns (uint256){

        return safe.safeMultiply(5, 10);

    }

}
```

Now, when deploying contract, I just have `deployer.deploy(myContract)` , It deploys the contract successfully and , `test` function works as expected. There was no need to use `deployer.link` from truffle.

So , why does the stackoverflow question above I linked or even truffle's website explain like this that `deployer.link` is needed to make this work ?