# Ethereum linking library with contract not working as accepted...returning any state variable returns just the default value

Tags: solidity, library

my library

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

library SafeMath {

    function add(uint256 a,uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

My contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract Test {

using SafeMath for uint256;

uint256 c = 10;

    function addition() public {
        uint256 a = 10;
        uint256 b = 10;
        c = a.add(b);
    }

    function getValue() view public returns (uint256) {
        return c;
    }

}
```

THE STEPS I AM FOLLOWING ARE:-

step 1 :- I am compiling SafeMath.sol  using commnadline  [solc --abi --bin safeMath.sol ]

step 2 :- I am deploying the same with web3 and getting the address as  0x785763........

step3 :- I am linking and compiling the Test.sol contract using the command 
solc --abi --bin Test.sol --libraries SafeMath:0x785763........ -o bin

step4 :- I am deploying this contract and trying to just get the value of c without performing the addition operation ,i am getting default value 0

also no events gets fired in addition method inside contract(not shown in this code)

//---------------------------------------------------
//MY WEB3 CODE

var UserRepositoryInstance1 = web3.eth.contract(UserRepositoryABI1).at(UserRepositoryAddress1);

app.get('/checkAdd', function (req, res) {
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;
var i=UserRepositoryInstance1.getValue();
console.log(i)
})

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED THANK YOU.

Comment: how are you calling the value c? with web3js ? remix? web3j?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this **--link** before --libraries, and see this answer it could help you

[What are the steps to compile and deploy a library in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/what-are-the-steps-to-compile-and-deploy-a-library-in-solidity)

Comment: yes i tried that got "linking complete" but the problem is the same

Comment: my contract bytecode has the address of library contained in it ...the deployment of the contract is also done without any error

Comment: but when i call getValue() from node(web3) i get the default value 0..

Comment: if i compile Test.sol first using command solc --optmize --bin Test.sol

Comment: can you upload your code somewhere?

Comment: the code is the same one as i have posted above only two of it...

Comment: i  just dont know why am i getting this wrong .....inspite of following the documentation strictly.....i have been stuck on this for five days know .........please any help would be appreciated

Comment: try 0.5.3 instead of 0.5.8,

Comment: i mean your wb3js code and how you are implementing getValue()

Comment: app.get('/checkAdd', function (req, res) {
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;
var i=UserRepositoryInstance1.getValue();
console.log(i);

Comment: if i remove the import library and compile the same with solc 0.4.24 ......i can call the get value and get the expected result.......the problem is either with the library or with the version......thank you for your answer ...... please look into   i just need to get this done

Comment: I think UserRepositoryInstance1.getValue() is async and need await before it Try please app.get('/checkAdd', async function (req, res) { web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase; var i = await UserRepositoryInstance1.getValue(); console.log(i); im not sure which web3js version you are using

Comment: the web3 version is 0.20.6.......and event making it synchronous is not working having the same problem......although i dont think the problem is with the asynchronous transaction as function is synchronous( am not sure)

Comment: same thing when i do using truffle it works(using deploy.link(a,b))

Comment: but i dont have option of doing with truffle so please help

Comment: ask on https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity, cause i have no more ideas :(